# pyspark dataframe complex calculation with previous row

Tags: pyspark, python-itertools

I am working with Pyspark and trying to figure out how to do complex calculation with previous columns. I think there are generally two ways to do calculation with previous columns : Windows, and mapwithPartition. I think my problem is too complex to solve by windows, and I want the result  as a sepreate row, not column. So I am trying to use mapwithpartition. I am having a trouble with syntax of this. 
For instance, here is a rough draft of the code.

```
def change_dd(rows):
    prev_rows = []
    prev_rows.append(rows)
    for row in rows:
        new_row=[]
        for entry in row:
            # Testing to figure out syntax, things would get more complex
            new_row.append(entry + prev_rows[0])
    yield new_row
updated_rdd = select.rdd.mapPartitions(change_dd)
```

However, I can't access to the single data of prev_rows. Seems like prev_rows[0] is itertools.chain. How do I iterate over this prev_rows[0]?

edit

```
            neighbor = sc.broadcast(df_sliced.where(df_sliced.id == neighbor_idx).collect()[0][:-1]).value
            current = df_sliced.where(df_sliced.id == i)
            def oversample_dt(dataframe):
                for row in dataframe:
                    new_row = []
                    for entry, neigh in zip(row, neighbor):
                        if isinstance(entry, str):
                            if scale < 0.5:
                                new_row.append(entry)
                            else:
                                new_row.append(neigh)
                        else:
                            if isinstance(entry, int):
                                new_row.append(int(entry + (neigh - entry) * scale))
                            else:
                                new_row.append(entry + (neigh - entry) * scale)
                    yield new_row
            sttt = time.time()
            sample = current.rdd.mapPartitions(oversample_dt).toDF(schema)
```

In the end, I ended up doing like this for now, but I really don't want to use collect in the first row. If someone knows how to fix this / point out any problem in using pyspark, please tell me.

edit2
--Suppose Alice, and its neighbor Alice_2

```
scale = 0.4
+---+-------+--------+
|age| name  | height |
+---+-------+--------+
| 10| Alice | 170    |
| 11|Alice_2| 175    |
+---+-------+--------+
```

Then, I want a row

```
+---+-------+----------------------------------+
|age        | name            | height        |
+---+-------+---------------------------------+
| 10+1*0.4  | Alice_2          | 170 + 5*0.4 |
+---+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: your discussion with @L.A. is confusing. Could you provide some example input rows and your expected result?

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus I added my temporary code in the question.

Comment: This does not make it clear for me, sorry. Q1: Do you (want to) use, in principle, `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` or `pyspark.RDD`? `DataFrame`s are stronly typed, so `isinstance(entry, str)` does not make any sense - either the entire column is `str` or it is not. The logic within the `for` loop seems perfectly fine to use with `Window`, together with a `join` to get new rows instead of a new column. But again, if you posted sample input rows and expected output, it would be much easier to help (you do not need to post actual data, make something up!)

Comment: 1. I am using dataframe. isinstance works, but is there any better way? I wanted to use dataframe.dtypes, but since i couldn't iterate by numbers (itertools.chain), I just used that way.
2. How do I smoothly create row from column without using column? Maybe that's point that I am missing. If I created column "result" by window, how do I make it into column with join ?

Comment: @TwUxTLi51Nus Thanks for help. I added an example input/output

Comment: You want the new `row` to be added to the old `dataframe`, or is it fine to have another dataframe? You want a new row for each pair of rows, i.e. `(row1, row2) -> new_row_1`, `(row3, row4) -> new_row_2`, or is it more like  `(row1, row2) -> new_row_1`, `(row2, row3) -> new_row_2`? In the first case, what defines such a pair?

Comment: I prefer to have another dataframe, so row1, row2 -> new_row_1.
I am going to select only two rows from the dataframe and perform the calculation.(selected one & knn from pyspark)

Comment: So for each row in the Dataframe you get its pair via KNN (from the same DataFrame)?

Comment: yes. Its part of oversampling algorithm, maybe there should be some more efficient way, but for now it is working in that way @TwUxTLi51Nus

Answer (score 0):

Why not using dataframes?

Add a column to the dataframe with the previous values using window functions like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark_session.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'Alice_2', 'age': 2}])

df.show()

+---+-------+    
|age|   name|   
+---+-------+   
|  1|  Alice|   
|  2|Alice_2|    
+---+-------+  



window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy('age')
df = df.withColumn("age-1", functions.lag(df.age).over(window))

df.show()
```

You can use this function for every column

```
+---+-------+-----+  
|age|   name|age-1|  
+---+-------+-----+   
|  1|  Alice| null|  
|  2|Alice_2|    1|  
+---+-------+-----+
```

An then just make your calculus

And if you want to use rdd, then just use `df.rdd`

Comment: I want to create a record out of it. If I use window and add column like that, whenever I do the calculation, I have to collect the data, which makes overall operation too slow.

Comment: So, I guess you want to use python, not Spark to do the calculus, don't you? What about using toPandas method of the dataframe?

Comment: No I want to use spark

Comment: I just want to make a dataframe row without having to use collect()